# Storage::Delete path location not overridden

Tags: laravel, image, local-storage, storage

[enter image description here][1]isn't this the way? but it's not deleting the image although its storing the image

if it is not the way then how can i override the public path in the 
controller?

edited(as suggested): i have added new disk "public" in my  filesystem.php, and controller modified by adding Storage facade .

---

in my controller.php

```
public function update(Request $request, $userId)
{
    $oldFileName='';
    $filenameToStore='';
    //saving the user
    $user=User::find($userId);
    $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');

    //for the image
    if ($request->hasFile('user_image')) {
        $image = $request->file('user_image');

        //get filename
        $filenameToStore= $image->getClientOriginalName();

       $location = public_path('chbea/users/images/' .$filenameToStore);

        Image::make($image)->save($location);
        $oldFileName =$user->user_image;

        Storage::disk('public')->delete('chbea/users/images/'. 
        $oldFileName);

        //saving user image name
        $user->user_image = $filenameToStore;
    }

    $user->save();
    Session::flash('success', 'The Student Details was Updated!');
    return redirect()->route('students.index');


}
```

in my filesystems.php

```
<?php

return [


'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),


'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),


'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('images/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
    ],

    /*'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],*/

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

  ],

 ];
```

and when i dd the output,path is not the intended one.

```
dd(Storage::disk('public'), 
  Storage::disk('public')>path('chbea/users/images/'.$oldFileName),
  Storage::disk('public')->exists('chbea/users/images/'.$oldFileName)
 [enter image description here][1]);
```

Here is the output
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/euVWR.png

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that you want to delete a file in the following path? `'allimages/project/users/images/' . $oldFilename`

Comment: actually not ..allimages and project are two different directories under public..... i want to keep that default path in filesystems.php and also want to override in controller to different location..is that possible? @Jonathon

Comment: Oh right I see. Yeah you can do that. I'll create an answer.

Comment: After your update, I've noticed a potential problem for you which is related to your logic rather than issues with `Storage::delete`. If you're uploading the same file, or a file with exactly the same name, your logic will first overwrite this file and then delete it straight after. This is because you're using `getClientOriginalName()` and using it as the filename and you're storing the file before you're deleting it. Could that be related to your problem?

Comment: actually..i have appended timestamps between filename and its extension..so each filename is unique..it's working when i use local disk..and yes i am storing the file before deleting from the public_path..but i have fetched $oldfilename from database. and want that old file to be deleted. @Jonathon is there any way to trace the error why it is not deleted?

Comment: Oh right, your code doesn't show any addition of timestamps. Try adding `dd(Storage::disk('public')->path('project/users/images/'.$oldFileName));` and seeing if the path that is shown matches the path to the file that you expect to be deleted

Comment: sorry for that..didn't want to add extra not important code, :D thank you, i will try..

Comment: "E:\projectchbea\project\storage\app/public\project/users/images/comment_1537952948.PNG"  @Jonathon

Comment: No problem. It's always a good idea to add as much code as possible even if you think it's not relevant, as your problem could be somewhere you might not expect or your stripped down code could lead someone to believe you have a problem somewhere when you don't. Does that path that you've shown me definitely match the path to the file that you expect to be deleted?

Comment: Nope ..it should be like this @Jonathon "E:\projectchbea\project\public\users\images\comment_1537952948.PNG"

Comment: Okay, so the path that you're actually seeing seems to match the path by the `public` disk that you have commented out, which is very strange. `public_path()` should return `/path/to/your/app/public`. Is the `public` disk that you have commented out in the code you posted, definitely commented out in your application?

Comment: yes, it is commented ..is the disk name "public"  used default by laravel which should be changed in different config file?is that likely to happen? @Jonathon

Comment: @Jonathon dd(Storage::disk('public')); returned me this "E:\projectchbea\project\storage\app/public\"

Comment: The default disk to use is configured in `filesystems.default`. If you don't specify a disk when you use the `Storage` facade, the default disk will be used. You should be specifying the disk name though using `Storage::disk('public')->delete(...)` though. `dd(Storage::disk('public'));` returning a path does not look right, do you not mean `dd(Storage::disk('public')->path());`?

Comment: @Jonathon nope..just  
         `dd(Storage::disk('public'));`
returned me 
         `adapter:Local
           #pathPrefix: "E:\projectchbea\project\storage\app/public\"`
and other parameters

Comment: Try this in your code, take a screenshot and add it to your question: `dd(Storage::disk('public'), Storage::disk('public')->path('project/users/images/'.$oldFileName), Storage::disk('public')->exists('project/users/images/'.$oldFileName));`

Comment: done. and thank you so much for your precious time . :) @Jonathon

Comment: You managed to fix it? No problem, you're welcome!

Comment: not fixed yet..but i am thinking to change local disk  from `root' => public_path('images/')`   to `root' => public_path()` ..hope it works @Jonathon

Comment: thank you so much sir @Jonathon .finally fixed ..just needed to run `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: Ah of course, I didn't think that your config might be cached. Glad you got it sorted. You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem here is that when you set up a filesystem like you have in your `filesystems.php` config, it *jails* that filesystem to the path you have defined. So in your case your `local` filesystem is jailed to `public_path('allimages/')`. You can't use that disk to go outside that filesystem.

You can create another disk that is jailed to a different location though:

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('allimages/'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path()
    ],
```

Here I have created another disk called `public` and jailed that disk to the public path. You can then use the storage facade like this:

```
Storage::disk('public')->delete('project/users/images/' . $oldFileName);
```

That will delete the file identified by the path you've given, relative to the `public` disk's root.

Comment: sorry it's not working ..i did exaclty like u said :( although image is saved to same location.but it won't be deleted @jonathon

Comment: Can you post your updated code in an edit, please? Both your filesystem configuration and your controller code, ideally. I'll take a look.

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. while trying to edit ..How do i deal with that  @Jonathon

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Maybe just add some text before your code saying something like "Edit: as requested below" and maybe add some text to describe what each bit of code is e.g. "This is my filesystem.php" etc.

Answer (score 0):

so this worked out finally ......

```
$oldFileName =$user->user_image;  
Storage::disk('customDisk')->delete('chbea/users/images/' . $oldFileName);
```

and in  my filesystems.php

```
 'customDisk' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path(),
 ],
```

and most important is to run this command otherwise u will get driver not supported error

```
  php artisan config:cache
```